# Use Instagram Picture in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, instagram-api

after reading https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/#media_redirect , I'm wondering if I can use the picture as an ImageIcon for SWING ?

Answer (score 4):

if the link provides a valid image then **you can** use it as image icon. following code can be useful in achieving in what you want

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {             
               String fullUrlPath = "your image path";
               try {
                  URL url = new URL(fullUrlPath);
                  BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
                  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, icon);
               } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }                 
         }
      });
```

Comment: thank you for your comment 
your answer cleared the half of the matter , the other half being how to get  the link as the api is designed for javascript

Comment: @GhassenTounsi you can use a java wrapper for the api like jInstagram. Or you can write your own.